# Google Forms Apps Script Sidebar w/ iFrame is missing 16px

Tags: iframe, google-apps-script

I'm working on an Add On for Google Forms. The [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) does not open to it's full 300px width. Instead the body of my sidebar only contains 284px, which creates an ugly margin on the right hand side of the sidebar. I've been able to replicate this issue with the following code:

Code.gs file:

```
function onInstall() {
  onOpen();
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = FormApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Open Sidebar').addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
  menu.addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setTitle('Sidebar too Narrow');
  FormApp.getUi().showSidebar(html)
}
```

index.html file:

```
<div>
 Hello World!
</div>
```

I want to get rid of the ugly margin on the right, which I think is caused by nested iframes.

Comment: I don't see a `.setWidth(300);` method?

Comment: Thanks for your help. My understanding is the sidebar defaults to 300 px, so setting the width isn't necessary. However, when I add the setWidth(300) method to the above code I see the same output - a nested iframe whose width is 284px.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in an add-on I'm writing. I hope this gets resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with Mac and Chrome. Please check the google-apps-script-issues tracker here: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4733&thanks=4733&ts=1422283697#makechanges

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Chrome Dev tools to inspect the app, you'll see what element style needs adjusted...

```
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. After adding your style suggestion, when I inspect the body element I see: border: 0; display: block; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; and width 100%. However, I still see the 16px border. It looks like there are a series of nested iframes with body elements. I have to go down four levels  of iframes to see the body with the 284px width.

Comment: can you share a link to a copy of the doc with the Add-on ?

Comment: Thanks: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1IlD4Bp0qF35Jm90ZkzMM8vrlx09IQOxkN75o6zYMWyQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you referring to just the "Sidebar too narrow" text that is in the sidebar header section? That's the only part i see on my end that has any padding. Don't know why there are 3 iframes, i typically just see 2, but the body and divs inside them all are 300 wide on my end.

Comment: Nope, for me it's the iFrame / body section not he header. Thanks for checking it out though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue in an add-on I'm writing. This smells a lot like a Chrome bug to me. I couldn't find it on the Chrome issue tracker, but I tested it in Canary (42.0.2289.0) and it works like it should.

So I'm assuming this is fixed within the next one or two versions of Chrome. Until then I'm just not going to worry about it.

Like @bryan-p mentioned, you will still need:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

but that's unrelated to this bug.

Comment: I tried my code in Safari and it looks fine. So I think you are right, this may be a Chrome issue. Thanks for your assistance.